# C# Validating date pattern

Tags: c#, .net, date

I'm working in a framework to generate code. One of the properties for date & time fields is its format. It must be a format accepted by `DateTime.ToString()`, example `dd/MM/yyyy`. How I can validate if the mask typed in the application is a valid datetime pattern for `.ToString()`?

Comment: You've got all sorts of culture and calendar issues to worry about here - can you get away with using DateTime.TryParse( )?

Comment: Can you just do a try/catch around a `DateTime.ToString()` with the given format to determine if it will break or not? Not exactly elegant but probably the easiest to program given the requirements. :)

Comment: @Chris IMHO programming by exception should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Liath, I don't need to validate the date. I need to validate just the format mask. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: @Liath: I will agree with that but the other option seems to be validating the format by fully parsing it which seems a) brittle and b) hard.

Comment: @Chris, thanks a lot. If there is no more elegant options, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Posted my comments as an answer now then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First variant uses System.Globalization. Second is dirty.

```
static bool ValidateFormat(string customFormat)
{
    return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customFormat) && customFormat.Length > 1 && DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns().Contains(customFormat);
}

static bool ValidateFormat(string customFormat)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime.Now.ToString(customFormat);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally if the actual requirement is that a given format must cause `DateTime.Now.ToString(format)` to not throw an exception then to my mind the most reliable way to do this is to just use that code in a try/catch block and if it throws an exception deal with it as appropriate.

One thing to note is that the `ToString` code is dependant on a `DateTimeFormatInfo` object. This may invalidate certain formats though I can't be sure. If it did it would be likely to do with different calendars and such like. It may only be needed for localisation options though. It is certainly worth testing with all (or at least a representative sample) of the locales you are interested in or best case just use the `ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)` overload of `DateTime.ToString`.

As others have commented on the question programming while expecting exceptions is not usually good practice but in this case I believe this it is the best match because a) it fits the requirements perfectly and b) the other options would be much harder to program and thus be much more likely to have bugs in.

Here's a sample method you might use. Note that I specifically catch the FormatException and not all exceptions in case something else freaky goes wrong that we don't want to catch.

```
public static bool ValidateDateFormat(string format, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime.Now.ToString(format, provider);
        return true;
    }
    catch(FormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so simple...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        string reg = @"^\bdd/MM/yyyy\b$";
        string reg1 = @"^\byyyy-MM-dd\b$";
        if (Regex.IsMatch(s, reg))
            Console.WriteLine("true");
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(s, reg1))
            Console.WriteLine("true");
        // and so on..

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

OR

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        string reg = @"(?<dateMatch>(^\bdd/MM/yyyy\b$)|(^\byyyy-MM-dd\b$))";

        if (Regex.IsMatch(s, reg))
            Console.WriteLine("true");

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

This method will match the both date patterns. "dd/MM/yyyy" and "yyyy-MM-dd" . 
Add as many patterns as you want to match.

Comment: So if the format is `yyyy-MM-dd` then how does that regex help?

Comment: What if it were `yyyy MM dd` or `yyyy MMM dd` or `MMMM \'yy`... You can't really just add a regex for each possibility...

Comment: yes as you only want to validate the pattern than you must have to define the patterns explicitly.

Comment: the whole point of the question though is that the format is user definable and should accept anything that `DateTime.ToString` does. This means that even though it is gibberish the following that I randomly typed on my keyboard (expecting random input to fail) in fact works for ToString and thus should be accepted: `aszvxcgzsxd;fkzsxdf`. Note that this is a case where it probably would actually be fine to fail but it highlights that you really can't enunmerate all valid inputs.